# Get key value pair of hash for the given key , in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a hash h1, and key k1. I need to return complete key value pair for the given key in the hash.

Like for key 'fish'
i need to print 'fish' => 'aquatic animal'

@h1, prints all the key value pairs.I need the way to print the key value pair for thr given key

I am quite new to ruby, so sorry for the noobish question.

Comment: Ruby hash keys are accessed with `[]`, so `puts "fish => #{h1["fish"]}`

Comment: Thanks,
But i need the output in the form hash.inspect returns(formatted string).Hence was wondering if ruby supports this directly for specified key.
 My test case is breaking because of the format.

Comment: I got a workaround, by creating a new hash, from the key value pair, and then outputting its value

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a method, Hash#assoc can do similar things. But it returns the key and value in an array, which you can easily change it into a hash.
And an alternative is use Hash#select, which does return a hash according to the block given.

```
h1 = { "fish" => "aquatic animal", "tiger" => "big cat" }
h1.assoc "fish"                       # ["fish", "aquatic animal"]
h1.select { |k,v| k == "fish" }       # {"fish"=>"aquatic animal"}
```

Answer (score 8):

in ruby >= 1.9

```
value_hash = Hash[*h1.assoc(k1)]
p value_hash                 # {"fish"=>"aquatic animal"}
```

in ruby < 1.9

```
value_hash = Hash[k1, h1[k1]]
p value_hash                 # {"fish"=>"aquatic animal"}
```

Answer (score 4):

The most easy and native way are using the method `slice`.

```
h1 = { fish: 'aquatic animal', tiger: 'big cat', dog:  'best human friend' }
k1 = :fish
```

Just do it:

```
h1.slice(k1)
# => {:fish=>"aquatic animal"}
```

And better, you can use multiples keys for this, for example, to k1, and k3

```
k1 = :fish
k3 = :dog

h1.slice(k1, k3)
# => {:fish=>"aquatic animal", :dog=>"best human friend"}
```

Clear, easy and efficiently

Answer (score 2):

Simplest answer:

```
def find(k1)
  {k1 => h1[k1]}
end
```

this will return {'fish' => 'aquatic animal'} which is what you need.

no need to jump through hoops to get they key, since you already have it! :-)

Answer (score 0):

I got a workaround, by creating a new hash, from the key value pair, and then outputting its value by using puts h1